# Selenium 3.4 how to use changed wait.until

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium3

So with Selenium 3.4 my previously working `wait.until`s aren't working (been replaced by new method). I can't seem to get the new method working though.

I'm using

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
```

Old code:

```
public boolean waitForURLToMatch(String expectedURL, int waitTime){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime);
    wait.until(EcpectedConditions.urlMatches(expectedURL));
}
```

New code:

```
public boolean waitForURLToMatch(String expectedURL, int waitTime){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime);
    wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, boolean>){

        @Override
        public boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return driver.getCurrentUrl().equals(expectedURL);
        }
    }
}
```

The new code has an error in eclipse:
`Syntax error on tokens, InterfaceHeader expected instead`

Any ideas on where I've gone wrong?

Comment: [`urlMatches`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#urlMatches-java.lang.String-) will check for Regex, use `urlToBe` or `urlContains`. Also If you are not using any explicit function of guava library there is no need to update that.. And there Error you have mentioned is fixed in latest verion

Comment: @Madhan thanks for your response, how would I use urlToBe or urlContains, the until method has been changed, the predicate has been removed, there is now only until(Function<?super WebDriver,V>isTrue).

I'm not sure of any error I've mentioned?

Comment: Use `ExpectedConditions` in the `wait.until()`.

Comment: @Madhan until was changed in 3.2 and no longer accepts ExpectedConditions, hence the reason for this question.

Comment: This works to me. With one small detail. 

It refers to Boolean the object, not boolean the primitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after much googling I eventually found the issue is just the syntax.

This works:

```
public boolean waitForURLToMatch(String expectedURL, int waitTime){
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime);
    Function<WebDriver, Boolean> function = new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            if(currentURL.equals(expectedURL))
            {
                truefalse = true;
                return truefalse;
            }
            truefalse = false;
            return truefalse;
        }
    };
    try{
        wait.until(function);
    } catch (TimeoutException e){   
    }
    return truefalse;
}
```

EDIT: Ok so it seems this was just a classpath conflict and all now works, the classpath conflict in conjunction with Selenium removing the deprecated until(predicate) confused the matter.